# Http response codes not changing, calling die() acceptable?

Tags: php, api, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I have developed a php (5.5) API to interface with the databases on my server. So far everything is running smoothly except for the part where I want to send http response codes.

If for example a user is not found in my database I want to return 404 to react accordingly in my application (android).

I could not get the status code to change from 200 using either:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found, true, 404);
```

or

```
http_response_code(404);
```

However, if I manually call die() like this:

```
http_response_code(404);
echo json_encode("Some response I want to send anyways");
die();
```

I get the expected status code.

Is calling die() like this acceptable? Or is there a better way to make sure my API sends the correct response codes?

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

**Edit 1:** This is not specific to 404 codes. I want my API to send other codes aswell.

Jasper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ending the script after setting proper response headers is generally the proper action. I'm not sure why it is not working for you without explicit `die` - make sure you're not outputting any data or headers afterwards that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to redirect to a 404 page.

```
header("location:404.php");
```

Comment: How to respond to 404 http status should be managed by web server or client, not enforced by application server.

Comment: I do not wish to redirect to a page. I need the response code so my client can react accordingly. This is not specific to 404 codes. (I have edited the question to clarify that)